# How do I back up a Wii U?

Tags: wii-u, hard-drive

Nintendo has [officially announced](https://en-americas-support.nintendo.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/57847/%7E/wii-u-%26-nintendo-3ds-eshop-discontinuation#s1q4) that they are shutting down the Wii U, and the 3DS eStores. I own a fair amount of digital games on my Wii U (they are on an external hard drive).

In the event that the hard drive dies or something and I can't redownload my games, is there any way I could back these digital games up from the hard drive to my computer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will still be able to download anything you've previously purchased [according to Nintendo](https://en-americas-support.nintendo.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/57847/%7E/wii-u-%26-nintendo-3ds-eshop-discontinuation#s1q4) "for the foreseeable future":

> #### How long will it still be possible to redownload previously purchased content in Nintendo eShop for Wii U or the Nintendo 3DS family of systems? How long will those systems still support online play?
>
> For the foreseeable future, it will still be possible to redownload games and DLC, receive software updates and enjoy online play on Wii U and the Nintendo 3DS family of systems.

Thus, there isn't any *immediate* need to backup your Wii U. I did however find [this site](https://cemu.cfw.guide/dumping-games.html#requirements), which requires a FAT32 USB or SD Card. It uses your Wii's browser to run an application for you to download your data to your computer.  It sounds like a lengthy process, but it's something to try at least. As always, do this at your own risk!

You'll need to follow these steps:

> ## Launching dumpling
>
> 1. Turn on your Wii U console
>
>    - If prompted, do not format any USB devices through the Wii U
> 2. Ensure that the title you want to dump has the latest update and any relevant DLC installed
>
>    - Some games, such as Breath of the Wild, require an update to function correctly in Cemu
> 3. If using a disk, ensure it is inserted before launching dumpling
> 4. Insert your USB storage device or SD card
> 5. Launch the internet browser and open `dumplingapp.com`
> 6. Tap `Launch dumpling`
>
>    - If your console freezes for more than 10 seconds, hold down the Power button for 4 seconds and reboot
>    - Once rebooted, reset the browser's save data and try again
>
> ## Using the dumpling app
>
> 1. Select `Dump digital games` or `Dump a game disc` depending on your scenario
>
>    - For Digital, select your games then press (START)
>    - For Disc, continue below
> 2. Verify that the dump's destination is correct (SD or USB)
> 3. Ensure your desired Wii U Account is set
> 4. Select `Start` to begin dumping
>
>    - This can take a very long time, we encourage you to dump one game at first.
> 5. Once finished, dump your next game at Step 1 or turn off your Wii U and put your SD or USB that you dumped to into your computer

Comment: "For the foreseeable future" -> It's been two years since the Wii eStore closed up shop, and you can still re-download purchases today. So big emphasis on "isn't any immediate need"